# React state not changing after clicking some button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios, event-handling

After invoking `handleButton` by pressing the `Log In` button once, the value of `logInStatus` is empty. However, after the second click,the value of `logInStatus` will change. I know that setState is an async call, so it will not update the value of `logInStatus` instantly.
How should I approach a solution?

```
import React, {setState, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
const Login = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = 'Log In';
    });
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [username, setName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [logInStatus, setlogInStatus] = useState('');
    const user = [password,username]
    
    function read(user){
        let returned = checkRegister(user);
        returned.then(function(result) {
            setlogInStatus(result.data.message);
            //return setlogInStatus(result)
         });
    }

    const handleButton = (e) => {
        read(user);
        e.preventDefault();
        //logInStatus is empty here even it should contain soimething
        if(logInStatus == "Successfully Authenticated"){
            //do stuff
        }
     }
    function checkRegister(user) {
        const user_object = {
            username: user[1],
            password: user[0]
        }
        console.log(user_object)
        var ok;
            return Axios({
                method: "POST",
                data: user_object,
                withCredentials: true,
                url: "http://localhost:9000/users/login",
              });
    }
    return(
        
        <div className="login">
             <div>
      </div>
            <div className="userform">
            <h2 className="pagename">Log in</h2>
            <form>
                {/* <label>Username:</label> */}
                <input
                    type="text"
                    required
                    value={ username }
                    onChange={ (e) => setName(e.target.value) }
                    placeholder="Username"
                />
                {/* <label>Password:</label> */}
                <input
                    type="password"
                    required
                    value={ password }
                    onChange={ (e) => setPassword(e.target.value) }
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <button onClick={handleButton}>Log In</button>
                <h1>{logInStatus} </h1>
            </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
    );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Have you test to `setlogInStatus(result)` directly into the result of the axios promise? Because, from my point of view, you already consume the promise with the first `then` in `checkRegister`, so you have two solution, first is what I tell above, the second is to return the promise unconsummed by removing the `then` in `checkRegister`.

Comment: Can you point out the line that throws the error?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol By second option do you mean what I did above(edited)? I removed the `then` in `checkRegister`  yet I still need to click the button twice to get the changed results of `logInStatus`

Comment: @Yousaf as the answer said `read` is a regular function so I cannot use `then`, so I shouldn't have defined another function. But I still failed t resolve the problem

Comment: @dogsht1338 yes, that's what I mean. Now you should not see the previous error, is it right?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol Yes, I dont get the error now, but the state of `logInStatus` is still not changing...

Comment: @dogsht1338 Ok well, now can you put the `function` keyword before `checkRegister`?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol yes I did, but it did not change anything. Thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit, I will not remove the first paragraph bellow, but it isnt right, use it as context for the @Yousaf comment bellow.**

*So, to resume, you have tried to call `then` on a promise which was already consume by the first `then` you putted into `checkRegister`. Which cannot work related to how handle a promise, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.
As I said you have to choose between, consume it directly into `checkRegister` or consume after into your `read` function. And set the state according to the choice you did before, where you have access to your result.*

You have to put the keyword `function` before `checkRegister` to declare it as it.

You can remove `var ok;` which is useless and used here.
You can remove too the import called `setState`, unused too.

And finally, you can remove the `e.preventDefault();` which is useless in your case because you are using a simple button, not connected to your form. You can learn more about forms here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: _"you have tried to call then on a promise which was already consume by the first then"_ - `then()` method also returns a promise and the promise it returns is resolved with the value returned by its callback function.

Comment: @Yousaf, you are right the problem of this code was about the `function` keywords, this is why we get a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Only because `checkRegister` was not using the `function` keyword. I will edit my comment. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

In the read function make sure that checkuser returns a promise.You can use then and catch only in case of js promises.From your code it is clear that checkuser is not a promise its just a function so just change it to a promise or otherwise remove the then method.
Check this out to learn about [js promises](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)